# Accessing spark console from browser

Tags: scala, apache-spark

is there anyway to access spark console of a cluster from some URL & browser, so that I can get RDDs from HDFS and do transformations/actions. If there is no ready way, how can I proceed designing/coding this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this MAY be of help

https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel

It's part of the http://jupyter.org/ project